# Get email address from Outlook

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, outlook

I am trying to output the email address of the current user through an Outlook addon. I haven't been able to get any other examples to work. The closest I have come is:

```
emailitem.SenderEmailAddress
```

which outputs:

```
Smith, John
```

but I want:

```
JohnSmith@hotmail.com
```

Any Ideas??

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: ...Its being accessed using a webpage made in ASP.Net

Comment: Is the web page getting the data from Outlook? Can you post the code? You can't using Office Automation from a server application.

Comment: Whoever down voted my legit question, thanks for nothing. Anyway I found the solution myself.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I was waiting for you to tell me if you were using Office Automation from a web application.

Comment: Hey John, sorry I wasn't accusing you. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Maybe this is not my place but imagine someone  gets stuck for a solution searches for what your question is about and lands on this page and bam there is no answer or solution to their problem. Yet there is somebody who knows the answer but is not telling. The fact that somebody asks a question and there after they stumble aupon an answer after having sought for help therefore implores them to divulge how they came to the solution. There has to be a give and take rather than just take, take take.

Comment: thanks for reminding me to post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim addrEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry = Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry
                    If addrEntry.Type = "EX" Then
                        Dim currentUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser = Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
                        If currentUser IsNot Nothing Then
                            MsgBox("Name: " + currentUser.Name)
End If
```